# Mac CRM software with iCloud Contacts integration

Tags: icloud, software-recommendation, contacts

I'm looking for *basic* customer relationship management (CRM) software that syncs with iCloud Contacts. I'm *not* looking for software that imports contacts into its own proprietary database. I'm seeking software that, like BusyContacts and Contacts.app, works with iCloud Contacts. It reads and writes to the .vcf or Vcard files themselves, so its changes are viewable in contact management software.

Comment: The more I use BusyContacts, the happier I am with it. All it lacks is a sales pipeline, and I've submitted that as a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the software, but it seems like [Contacts Journal](http://www.contactsjournal.com/) may do what you're looking for, with two caveats:

1. new contacts entered in Contacts.app are not automatically imported into Contacts Journal, but it will automatically prompt you to do so, and thereafter keep the contacts sync'd
2. contacts added directly in Contacts Journal will not automatically appear in Contacts.app, and I don't see an indication of how to accomplish this.

There is a lite version that you can try for free, and also a [FAQ](http://www.contactsjournal.com/files/FAQ-word-v2.pdf).

I have no affiliation with the product.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, but the inability to sync automatically is a dealbreaker.